# How can I convert an array of numbers in javascript to string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Like I have `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`, I want this to become `arr["1","2","3","4","5"]`. I tried using:

```
var x = arr[0].toString(); //outputs "1"
```

but when I do `typeof x` it outputs "number".

How can I convert this that when I do `typeof` it will output "string"?

Answer (score 4):

Most elegant solution

```
arr = arr.map(String);
```

This works for `Boolean` and `Number` as well. Quoting MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and **strings returned from String calls in a non-constructor context** (i.e., without using the new keyword) are primitive strings.

As for VisioNs answer, this only works for browser that support [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arrOfStrings = arr.map(function(e) { return e + ""; });
```

Check the [browser compatibility and use shim if needed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

Comment: I'd rather use the native [.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FNumber%2FtoString) method instead of constructing a string.

Comment: @Simon Why, if not a secret?

Comment: Simply because it's more readable imho, you see what exactly is happening with the value.

Comment: Hm on the other hand your code is more bullet proof because it doesn't break if for some reason an array value should be `null` or `undefined`...

Comment: @Simon indeed, combining `null` or `undefined` with a blank string will convert it to a string.

Comment: Post this as an answer @Prinzhorn, probably the most elegant way to handle the task.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a more elegant way of doing this but you could loop the array and convert each value to a string by adding it to a blank string `+=""`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971039/javascript-string-and-number-conversion) for javascript type conversions

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) arr[i]+="";
alert(typeof arr[0]) //String
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
arr.join().split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this too: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/VtjAy/1/)** (if you want to use `.toString()`)

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var i = 0;
arr.forEach(function(val) {
    arr[i] = val.toString();
    console.log(typeof(arr[i]));
    i++;
});
```