# "-" Operator in javascript ? how its working?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = "5";
var y = 2;
var z = 5-("1"+2)+"2"+"1";
console.log(z) // -721
```

How is this possible? Please explain about - operator in javascript

Comment: Kindly Google it. You will find it in JavaScript Specs.

Comment: It's due to type coercion/conversion. The `-` operator expects its operands to be numbers and converts values of any other type to a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript string and number conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971039/javascript-string-and-number-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`("1"+2)` gives you `"12"` via concatenation.

`5-"12"` gives you `-7` because, as Jonathan pointed out, `-` expects numbers and casts them as necessary.

Then you concatenate `-7+"2"+"1"` to give you the string `"-721"`

It's really just an order of operations problem, with concatenation happening after the arithmetic of 7-"12", except in the case where it is in parenthesis to make the "12" in the first place.

Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break var `var z = 5-("1"+2)+"2"+"1";` down

1. The elements in the quotes are read as string, which therefore becomes a concatenation as suppose to an addition. Because `("1" + 2)` is in brackets, it will have precedence. `("1" + 2) = 12`

Now you have `5-12+"2"+"1";`. Let's break it down into two parts

```
5 - 12 AND "2" + "1"

a. 5 - 12 = -7
b. "2" + "1" = "21"
```

Now you have `-7 + "21"`. Since one is a String, it is a concatenation resulting in `"-721"`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggested you to read

- [Stackoverflow Javascript Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)
- [Javascript Try](https://www.javascript.com/try)

There are many resources which could answer all of your question.