# addition jquery - conflict with concatenation

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with addition two numbers.

```
 var dobanda = $('.dobanda').val();
 var val1 = $('.amount1').val();
 $('.total_suma').val(dobanda + val1);
```

dobanda = 100

val1 = 30

show: 10030

Comment: Convert them to integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript string and number conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971039/javascript-string-and-number-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Please node you may need to use parseInt or parseFloat depending on your value.

```
var dobanda = parseInt($('.dobanda').val());
var val1 = parseInt($('.amount1').val());
$('.total_suma').val(dobanda + val1);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert a variable into integer or float.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

This is how you have to do.

```
 var dobanda =parseFloat($('.dobanda').val());
 var val1 = parseFloat($('.amount1').val());
 $('.total_suma').val(dobanda + val1);
```

parseInt will neglect the decimal points and will give you only integer value.Use parseFloat if you have decimal points(eg. 10.59)

> Example

```
var number1 = parseInt(10.59);
var number2 = parseFloat(10.59);
```

> Result:

```
number1=10;
number2=10.59
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to integer using parseInt.

```
 var dobanda = $('.dobanda').val();
 var val1 = $('.amount1').val();
 $('.total_suma').val(dobanda + val1);
```