# How do you represent a number as a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a node-red flow that needs to create an MQTT payload.

The payload is a temperature reading from an I/O card, calculated as a float (73.4 for example).

I need the message payload to be a string, not a number; something like "Barn Temp is 73.2". How can I create this?

```
msg.payload = tempReading;               // gives a number
msg.payload = ""+tempReading;            // returns NaN
```

A bonus question: if I did use this as a numeric payload how can I specify its format?  The reading is calculated at 73.18527461364; I need to send this as 73.2.

I'm having a devil of a time finding out how to format strings in javascript!

Comment: String + Number produces string. Example doesn't make sense unless `tempReading` is  `NaN` in second one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript string and number conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971039/javascript-string-and-number-conversion)

Comment: just use toFixed(1) to format 73.185..  as 73.2

Comment: And `.toFixed()` lets you truncate the fractional part (returning a string)

Comment: Thanks for the shortcuts.  I see where the person who posed the referenced answer was bashed for asking a question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) is an easy surefire way to convert numbers to strings.

```js
var x = 10.56;
x = x.toString();
console.log(x, typeof x);
```

If you want to control how many decimal points are displayed, you can use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
var x = 12.3456789;
x = x.toFixed(3);
console.log(x, typeof x);
```

Comment: I'd love to improve my answer if someone could explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Perfect! And msg.payload=reading.toFixed(1).toString() worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 74.3; //=> typeof num "number"

var converted = String(num); //=> typeof converted "string" "74.3"
```

In your case, just do:

```
msg.payload = String(tempReading);
```