# Sum of a javascript array returns a string concatenation of all the numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm having a php json_encode object fetched by ajax. whet I want to do is to sum this array. Here's what I did so far:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var tot = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
   tot.push(json[i].final_total);
   $('table tbody').append("<tr><td>" + json[i].order_id + "</td><td>" + json[i].final_total + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Now I want to sum this array. I tried this:

```
var sum = tot.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
$("#total").html( sum );
```

But the result is:

```
09.748.529.129.129.119.59.79.89.79.89.79.79.79.79.79.79719.248.59.79 ......
```

I also tried:

```
myFunction(tot); 

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = item.reduce(getSum);
}
```

But I got the same result above (Numbers written next to each other).

I also tried this:

```
var tot = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
   tot += json[i].final_total);
   $('table tbody').append("<tr><td>" + json[i].order_id + "</td><td>" + json[i].final_total + "</td></tr>");
}
$("#total").html( tot );
```

But I got the same result above (Numbers written next to each other).

So what is the proper way to sum an array in javascript?

Comment: use a [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Seems like `json[i].final_total` are strings, so your reduce just concatenates them. You could for example `tot.push(+json[i].final_total);`. The unary `+` will cast the value as a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript string and number conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971039/javascript-string-and-number-conversion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `parseInt` (if the numbers are **Integers**), `parseFloat` (if they are **Floats**) or `Number` (if not sure) to explicitly interpret them as numbers like:

```
sum = tot.reduce((a, n) => (a + Number(n)), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Array elements are `strings`, in order to properly add them, they have to be casted to `integer`:

```
var sum = tot.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}, 0);
```

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators):

> the concatenation operator (+) concatenates two string values together, returning another string that is the union of the two operand strings.

The is a common issue caused by `+` operator used for both string concatenation and addition. Issue is best described with following example:

```
var result = '1' + 3 + 3 + 7 //result is '1337'
```

Edit: @Pointy - Nice catch, thanks! :)

Comment: Those values look like they've got fractional parts, so `parseInt()` is the wrong approach.

Comment: Plus no need to parseInt `a`. It already a number.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use a parse int because its concatenating the sting instead of adding integers

```
var sum = tot.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return parseInt(pv) + parseInt(cv); }, 0);
```

[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)